# Only One Database or Many?

Tags: php, mysql, database, symfony

I'm trying to create web application in php, using symfony.
It's sort of a **community creator**. But my question is, should I make only one database for all the application, or should I create a database every time a user creates a "community". What are the best practices, in relation to this. Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: It depends. I think at first, I would go for a single database. But if there are many communities with many users and lots of traffic, then a single MySQL database might not suffice. The advantage of having separate databases, is that you can move each of them to a separate server or cluster. But my that time, you will probably have found out if MySQL is suitable at all for an application like this.

Comment: not enough detail to answer with anything but opinions. but if the communities all have the SAME basic data structure, then a single db makes sense. if each community is wildly different in structure, then multiple dbs.

Comment: It would be more scalable and portable if you made the communties self sufficient (meaning, give them each their own database and codebase) so that if a community outgrows your server, you can simply migrate it elsewhere.

Comment: I think, when user creates a comunity you should to create a row in your Comunities table) Or document in collection :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new database every time a user creates a new community is a bad idea in my opinion, for more than a few reasons. I'll give you the most important ones:

- It's very unsafe. It means that the overall database user that is connecting to the database server has a higher level of privileges (beyond the standard CRUD operations). That is considered bad security practice, as a security flaw in your application could open the databases for all kinds of attacks.
- It's hard to maintain. I'm not sure how many communities you expect to get, but imagine that an update of the code requires you to update a given table in all of those databases.
- For each database another connection is used, which means that another socket connection is in use. When using persistent connections, this means a lot of database connections may be open at the same time (depending on the scale of the application). This could cause bottlenecks and thus performance issues.

The first and second reasons are by far the most important.

If, however, you feel the need to separate each community from another in some way, I suggest using tables with a prefix for every community. In that case the first reason is migitated somewhat, as the database user only has to have rights to a single database, and the third reason is no longer in order.